# I do not get this --- int x = 0; int y = 2; int z = (++x, ++y);

Tags: c++

```
int x = 0; 
int y = 2; 
int z = (++x, ++y);
```

I get that z is 3 because the value is taken from ++y, but why is ++y being chosen?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh(v=vs.110).ASPX

Answer (score 3):

It's called `comma operator`. It evaluates `++x`(now x is 1), then evaluates `++y`(now y is 3) and assign value of `y to`z``

The ``comma operator groups left-to-right.
§ 5.18

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right and the value of **the left expression is discarded**.

Answer (score 2):

Because (++x,++y) evaluates `++x` first, then `++y` and whatever was evaluated last is returned and assigned to `z`.

Answer (score 0):

This uses [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The equivalent is:

```
int x = 0; 
int y = 2; 
++x; // or x = x + 1;
++y; // or y = y + 1;
int z = y;
```